# How to permanently disable wifi?

Tags: android

How to permanently disable WiFi, so the users won't be able turn it on again?
This is a requirement of the customer of our special Android base devices.
I have renamed files in /data/misc/wifi/.
Then it is impossible to turn on WiFi in Settings.
But after reboot it is still possible to turn on WiFi again.
I have just entered new settings for WiFi routers.
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry what? Do you want WiFi not to be working again, ever? If you just disable wifi, change settings for your router, and enable it again. Is that not enough?

Comment: can't understand very well.

Comment: No, I need to turn wifi off for users, so that users can't turn it on

Answer (score 1):

Root the device or Build a custom ROM so that you can permanently disable wifi easily... I hope you won't find a better solution....